# CPU monitoring tool for Centos

Tags: centos

I'm looking for a CPU monitoring tool that could monitor the different processors in my machine, and also has a GUI (similar to the Ubuntu monitoring tool).

Is there anything like that in Centos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# yum info gnome-system-monitor

Name        : gnome-system-monitor
Arch        : i686
Version     : 2.28.0
Release     : 11.el6
Size        : 1.8 M
Repo        : base
Summary     : Process and resource monitor
URL         : http://www.gnome.org/
License     : GPLv2+
Description : gnome-system-monitor allows to graphically view and manipulate the running
            : processes on your system. It also provides an overview of available resources
            : such as CPU and memory.
```

to install, type:

```
# yum install gnome-system-monitor
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

The tried and true [gkrellm](http://freecode.com/projects/gkrellm) is always out there :)  It has some great themes and provides a ton of useful information in a small footprint.  I'm sure there are many more recent projects out there, but to celebrate the release of E17 I offer `gkrellm` up as my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Not to be flippant but you could use:

```
xterm -e top
```

I know it doesn't have magic buttons, but it's very powerful, can have colors and does have an interactive help (press `?` or `h`).

This is actually what I use, since it works on just about every *nix.

Answer (score 1):

**Conky** is a popular GUI widget style monitor akin to gkrellm, both of which should be available as a centos package (they're in fedora).  Google and you'll find pictures, etc.

Personally I like gkrellm, but either one could be configured just as a CPU gauge, either "compound" or per-core.